# Assembly - How to properly use stack between function call

Tags: linux, assembly, gdb, x86-64, stack-memory

I'm confused with how to use the stack in assembly. I'm trying to understand how can I pass and read variables between functions, for this purpose, I've written a short program and I'm debugging it using gdb (I'm writing using sasm on VMWare running on Linux).

Here's my code:

```
.text
.global main
main:
    movq $7, %rax
    movq $2, %r13
A:
    pushq %rax              # insert 7
    pushq %r13              # insert 2
    call B
    popq %r13
    popq %rax
    dec %rax
    inc %r13
    cmp $5, %r13
    je end
    call A
    addq $8, %rsp
    ret
B:
    movq 8(%rsp), %rcx        # pop 2
    movq 16(%rsp), %rdx       # pop 7
    xorq %rax, %rax
end:
    ret
```

It works as expected, but exits with exit code 04 and also when I look at the stack, it behaves oddly. I have two things I'm not sure about:

Firstly, I understood that after each call I need to increase rsp somehow (by using pop or add) in order to prevent segmentation faults. i.e after the line

```
call A
```

I must pop the stack by the number of element I inserted to it before the calling occurred + 8 because of the ra. If I haven't pushed any elements, I just need to increase the rsp by 8 because the ra is still there and I can't return from my program in this case. but when I'm running the command which is being executed at the end of the program:

```
    addq $8, %rsp
```

The stack looks like this:

```
#0  0x00000000004005d5 in A ()
#1  0x00007ffff7a05b97 in __libc_start_main (main=0x4005a7 <main>, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe028, init=<optimized out>,
    fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffe018) at ../csu/libc-start.c:310
#2  0x00000000004004ea in _start ()
```

I thought it will be empty. why do I still see A in #0 and what is the standard library doing there? from what I understand, I don't need to touch this information, but isn't this just like exiting with some info on the stack? I mean, can't it cause sigsegv?

I've tried looking online about the exit code 4 which I thought was somehow related, but I only found "problem with opening file" (which is clearly not the case) and "Network problems" which I don't see how it is related with the fact that I'm exiting without popping all elements on the stack. after running `strace` I've got the following output:

```
execve("./stak", ["./stak"], 0x7ffe6ace7370 /* 51 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x18ce000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=104376, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 104376, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd062dab000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260\34\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2030544, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd062da9000
mmap(NULL, 4131552, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd0627ad000
mprotect(0x7fd062994000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fd062b94000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1e7000) = 0x7fd062b94000
mmap(0x7fd062b9a000, 15072, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd062b9a000
close(3)                                = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fd062daa4c0) = 0
mprotect(0x7fd062b94000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x600000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7fd062dc5000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fd062dab000, 104376)          = 0
exit_group(4)                           = ?
+++ exited with 4 +++
```

which I couldn't understand. I can see that it failed opening some files because of ENOENT, but I don't understand what files. couldn't find anything at the man manual also.

What am I doing wrong? Why is my stack still holds elements? am I using the stack correctly? and perhaps someone knows what's exit code 4 means? aside from what I've already specified, I've also tried looking online, but found nothing related.

---

### Edit

After removing the line with the command addq, the program runs fine, and my stack looks like this just before returning from the program:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000004005d1 in A ()
#1  0x00000000004005d1 in A ()
#2  0x00007ffff7a05b97 in __libc_start_main (main=0x4005a7 <main>, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe028, init=<optimized out>,
    fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffe018) at ../csu/libc-start.c:310
#3  0x00000000004004ea in _start ()
```

Does it make sense that I have 2 ra of A?

Comment: The return address is popped by `ret`. Stack is not empty because `main` is called by the C library startup code. Even if it wasn't, the OS would already populate the stack with some data at least. The exit code is whatever you return from `main` in `al`. Since you decrement `rax` 3 times starting from 7 that gives 4. `addq $22, %rsp` is plain simply wrong, it isn't even a multiple of 8 and there is nothing to remove from the stack at that point. I am surprised your code doesn't crash. It does here.

Comment: @Jester. so from what you've said I understand that running the commend add is not necessary and can lead to problems? but If I remove it, I'm getting segmentation fault...
and I don't know how I've managed to copy it with mistakes, but it's not 22 it's 8. and apart from all the rest, am I using this correctly? does anything else looks bad?

thank you very much for your help!

Comment: `addq $8, %rsp` might accidentally work but that removes a return address needed for proper operation. Double check that you really get a crash without that `addq`.

Comment: @Jester your'e right, it's runs just fine. but my stack now has 2 ra of A, is it ok? will ret figure it out by himself? thank you once again!

Comment: Since you `call A` recursively, having multiple entries is fine depending on when you are looking at the stack.

Comment: @Jester I understand. thank you!

Comment: Your code isn't JavaScript; don't use Java Script code snippet blocks, just normal code-formatting.